# Autocomplete does not clear while click the remove (x) icon in textbox

Tags: bug

Autocomplete does not clear the values via clicking the remove button in textbox (input filed)

When I type `"a"` in autocomplete:

> [image]

When I clear the textbox using <kbd>backspace</kbd>, it's working as expected:

> [image]

When again I entered `"a"`

> [image]

Now I clear the `"a"` by using click the `[x]` icon

> [image]

The input field value was cleared. But the autocomplete doesn't clear.
 It still showing the records.

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete event listener on that `input` element is registered to the `keyDown` event.

It's not responding to the `change` event, which gets triggered by the `[x]`.

See here, `change` is absent:

> [image]